# DNS client to lookup CNAME records automatically

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, google-cloud-dns, getaddrinfo

We've just migrated to a new internal DNS resolver, and discovered a limitation that impacts our ability to lookup specific records.

Our internal (private) authoritative domain is `example.net.`. We have a CNAME record for `service.example.net.` that resolves to `name-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com.`

`name-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com.` resolves to various A records, who's values are managed by AWS. We do not manage the public amazonaws.com zone, nor the records within this zone.

Our previous DNS resolver would "chase" CNAME records, so a lookup of `service.example.net.` might return this:

```
$ dig service.example.net
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
service.example.net.    300 IN  CNAME   name-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com.
name-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com. 26 IN A 10.1.2.3
name-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com. 26 IN A 10.1.2.4
```

The answer includes the IPs of the A records that the CNAME points to. All good.

Our new DNS resolver does not "chase" CNAME records. The same lookup with the new resolver looks like this:

```
$ dig service.example.net
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
service.example.net.    300 IN  CNAME   name-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com.
```

... note the missing A records. Attempts to contact `service.example.net` via ping, curl, python requests, etc. all result in "Unknown host" failures.

We're not able to change the behavior of our new DNS resolver. Is there some option in the linux kernel or some local DNS resolver to "chase" CNAME records from the client, the same way our old DNS resolver did at the server side?

For context, our new DNS resolver is GCP's cloud-dns, which [documents](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/cnamechasing) this behavior.

Some additional context / comment answers:

- example.net. is a private, internal managed zone in cloud-dns owned by us.
- amazonaws.com. is a public zone, managed by AWS.
- iirc, an outbound server policy with additional name servers will send *all* queries to those nameservers, overriding cloud-dns
- iirc, ALIAS records are only available in public zones, not private zones.
- service.exmaple.net. is a CNAME record in the private, managed cloud-dns zone example.net.
- we don't have a presence in AWS, so cannot use route53.

Comment: Your post is very interesting. You are using `dig` to make queries. That tool contains its own logic. Changing the kernel will not change the output of dig. How does the behavior of the Google resolver affect your system or applications? I do not see a problem to be fixed (yet). In the output from dig will be the server it queried. Which server is that? By default, dig queries the name servers listed in /etc/resolv.conf. Do not modify that file in GCP as it is overwritten. [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#resolv.conf)

Comment: In summary, the behavior dig exhibits does not reflect how applications resolve DNS. It is simply a debugging tool.

Comment: In my question, I'm using `dig` to show the different answers being sent by our old resolver, and cloud-dns. Any process doing DNS lookups would see the same - cloud-dns is not adding the A record lookups to it's response. The problem (as stated) is that this results in "Unknown host" errors.

Comment: You can change the VPC Outbound server policy [link](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/server-policies-overview#dns-server-policy-out) to add alternative name servers.

Comment: Your assumption is not always correct: `Any process doing DNS lookups would see the same`. The topic of recursive DNS is not so simple. For example, I have been deploying systems in Google Cloud for more than a decade and I have not experienced your problem. I also have extensive experience with DNS, so this question is very interesting to me. Can you share the DNS hostname that is causing the problem?

Comment: Another item. Azure DNS has the same behavior except for Azure Front Door endpoints [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/apex-domain). Since CNAME chasing is not widely implemented in the cloud DNS servers, this starts to look like a local system issue. Is `service.example.net` a delegated (hosted) zone or a CNAME record at `example.net`. Can you use a Route 53 ALIAS record instead of CNAME?

Comment: Why don't you use route53 in aws and forward aws queries to that?

Comment: @Turdie - that would break the VM's DNS for public name queries. Route 53 is not a Public Recursive DNS service like 1.1.1.1 (Cloudflare) or 8.8.8.8 (Google). I am not aware of a Google VPC policy to only forward AWS queries to Route 53.

Comment: No but you can use route53 to expose the dns records of your Aws resources and use a conditional forwarder in dns to forward the aws domains to route53. I would install an Windows dns server or bind dns server and use forwarders for google and awd

Comment: @Turdie - you are correct but now things are getting complicated quickly. I think there is a simple solution to the problem statement. Once she answers my questions, I might have a clue. I have a feeling that changing to ALIAS will solve her problem.

Comment: `We've just migrated to a new internal DNS resolver` why? And what went into that decision?

Comment: @JohnHanley et al. : appreciate your comments very much, I've updated the question with additional context to address some of your queries.

Comment: The issue is the private hosted zone is in Cloud DNS, so using an alternative name server will not help as a public recursive DNS server cannot resolve private hosted zones. Your problem now is that your setup will not CNAME chase. I recommend that you get Google Cloud involved. That will require paid support but that cost is minor compared to the cost of engineering time. Otherwise, I would create a public hosted zone in Route 53 and use ALIAS records instead of CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly pointing to the internal ips of the load balancer, you need to point to the public dns name of the load balancer

```
name-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com
```

So remove the a records and change the cname value to the public dns name of the load balancer

Comment: I should have been clearer in my original question - the initial CNAME does point to a real, public, amazonaws.com name somewhat like `name-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com`

Comment: That should be enough https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internet-facing-load-balancers.html